# Is there a way to disable key shortcuts like(alt + tab or windows + tab) while in kiosk mode in electron?

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron

I am creating a testing platform that will require my application to disable these shortcuts to have a test or exam in a cheating free manner. It was suggested to me to use kiosk mode for the same, but even after in **kiosk** mode, I can change tabs with the shortcuts.
Are there more customizations to `kiosk` option of `BrowserWindow` that I can do to achieve that. Thanks in advance for your help.

Target OS: Windows, Linux, MacOS but if solution for all of them is not possible, Only Windows will also suffice.

Comment: Might help to add which operating system. (My guess would be disabling those keyboard shortcuts would have to be at the OS-level, but there might be some OS-specific solution you could call from the Electron app. It might have to be specific to the desktop environment on Linux.)

Comment: I wish to make a cross-platform app for that a generic solution will be a lot better. Is it possible? My OS for development is Windows 10.